# cURL very long delay before starting download from ftp

Tags: ftp, curl

I'm trying to write a script to download a file, convert it, then execute a program on the converted file.

For some reason `curl` takes over 1 minute to start the file transfer.

Command:

```
curl ftp://tgftp.nws.noaa.gov/SL.us008001/ST.expr/DF.gr2/DC.ndfd/AR.conus/VP.001/ds.wx.bin -o test.out
```

I've tried disabling active and EPRT modes with `--ftp-pasv` and `--disable-eprt` but that doesn't seem to make a difference.

I've tried `--verbose` and that tells me where but I still have no idea why.

It logs in quickly and changes to the right directory, but as soon as it tries to download the file, it just sits there for over a minute. Just before the delay here is the verbose output:

```
* FTP 0x1c2b268 state change from CWD to PASV
* Connect data stream passively
< 229 Entering Extended Passive Mode (|||64103|)
```

The funny thing is that `wget` starts downloading immediately. I know I can use that, but I'd like to figure out why `curl` is having problems.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: From here it is fast, so it might be related to your location. Maybe you have some kind of firewall/DPI device in between which does have problems with `EPSV`. Try to make curl use `PASV` instead with `--disable-epsv`.

Comment: I have no idea what we do for a firewall, but that did it. Thank you very much! If you'd care to put it in as an answer, I'd be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was some kind of middlebox (firewall, deep inspection device etc) which produced problems with the EPSV command (passive mode for IPv6 and IPv4). Forcing PASV (passive mode IPv4 only) with `--disable-epsv` solved the problem. Similar problems could have been if the server had IPv6 and there were problems with IPv6 only, but in this case the server had no AAAA DNS record.